# How to create a new command line?

Tags: r, command-line, command

I have a very simple question, How to create a new command line?? my code is

```
barplot(Danes, col = rainbow(12), beside = T)
legend(locator(1), legend = rownames(Danes), col = rainbow(12), pch = rep(18, 12))
```

But when I click enter, it creates the graph but doesn't give me a new command line (<) or gave me the legend so I guess I must have messed the legend command up. how do I basically restart and keep my data and code?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `locator(1)`. R is waiting for you to click somewhere in the plot window (to decide where to put the legend).  Alternatively, if you want to cancel the action (from `?locator`):

> For the usual ‘X11’ device the identification process is
>        terminated by pressing any mouse button other than the first.  For
>        the ‘quartz’ device the process is terminated by pressing the
>        ‘ESC’ key.

(it doesn't say what to do for a Windows graphics device, but I'd try ESC and other mouse buttons and maybe Ctrl-C).